# ¿Como quitar los espacios de un CardView?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

Buenas estoy intentando crear un Cardview pero este se me sale del LinearLayout, les paso el código para ver si pueden ayudarme soy principiante y de seguro estoy haciendo algo mal.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                R.id.wrap_content, R.id.wrap_content);
        layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        layoutparams.height = 40;
        layoutparams.width = 40;

        CardView catCard = new CardView(getApplicationContext());
        catCard.setLayoutParams(new CardView.LayoutParams(
                CardView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 10));

        catCard.setMinimumHeight(10);
        catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC6D6C3"));
        content.addView(catCard);
```

Este es el código de mi actividad en `xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.omar.versionmejorada.Main2Activity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/maxresdefault"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="Buenos Aires2"
                        android:textColor="#121111"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="22dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
             android:id="@+id/card2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_margin="8dp">
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical">

                 <ImageView
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="250dp"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:src="@drawable/maxresdefault"
                     android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/txt1"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:padding="8dp"
                     android:text="Buenos Aires"
                     android:textColor="#121111"
                     android:textStyle="bold"
                     android:textSize="22dp" />
             </LinearLayout>
         </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Esta es la imagen de como me sale mi Cardview:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puede ver en la parte de abajo es cuando intento crear el CardVieW haciendo click en un boton pero este se me sale del LinearLayout espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: no se nota por donde sale del LinearLayout

Comment: lo quiero agregar al linearlayout que esta con ID:  id_content

Comment: @o.flores que sucede no funciono?

Answer (score 2):

Para remover el padding lo puedes realizar agregando una medida negativa de `contentPadding` en dp, pero lo ideal es la propiedad **[setPreventCornerOverlap](http://setPreventCornerOverlap)** con valor false para deshabilitar el padding.

> **PreventCornerOverlap**: En las plataformas pre-lollipop, CardView no recorta los límites de la Tarjeta para las esquinas redondeadas. En su lugar
>   , agrega un padding (contenido de relleno) que no se sobrepone con las
>   esquinas redondeadas. **Puedes deshabilitar este comportamiendo 
>   estableciendo este campo en false**.

Puedes agregar a tu Widget también la propiedad `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`   :

Agrega en tu `CardView` esta propiedad para eliminar el padding:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
         android:id="@+id/card2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_margin="8dp"
         card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto las cardView tienen un padding asignado, para eliminarlo se puede utilizar en el xml:

```
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

o en tiempo de prgramación:

```
catCard.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
```

A pesar de esto, el comportamiento natural es tener padding para el efecto de profundidad, por lo tanto, seria buena idea usar otro tipo de contenedor si no se usan sus características.

Comment: No tienen un pad asignado, esto sucede únicamente en los dispositivos con OS pre-lollipop.